# Python Requests HTTP sub-codes response

Tags: python, http, python-requests

In the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module of Python, we can check the response of a request as below:

```
>>> resp = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
>>> resp.status_code == 200
True
>>> resp.status_code == requests.codes.OK
True
>>>
```

What can I do if I just need to check if the response that came, is a part of the [HTTP sub-codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) , viz.,

1xx (Informational responses)

2xx (Success)

3xx (Redirection)

4xx (Client errors)

5xx (Server errors)

Comment: just use `resp.status_code // 100 == 2`

Comment: @BearBrown haha that was soo simple..

Answer (score 0):

They will always be a part of HTTP sub-codes response. I cant think of a time where it would be different. 
Check the status with resp.status_code like you are doing and Write a bunch of if stmts to make the code do what you want with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following to do what you might need.

```
def convert_to_xx(status_code):
    m = re.match(r'(?P<code>\d{1})\.*', str(status_code))
    return m.group('code') + "xx"
```